# Can't filter the table in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, model

I am making a javafx project, where I am supposed to filter the data from xml and display it in a table. There is a textfiled that I am trying to use as a searching field such that whatever is typed in it is searched through the entries inside the table and incase of match only those entries are displayed that has a positive match. 
This is my model class:

I am extracting the data from an xml file using a Wrapper for the my Model Class.

Model Class:

```
private final StringProperty fileSubject;
private final StringProperty fileDate;
private final StringProperty fileRemarks;

public void setFileSubject(String fileSubject){
    this.fileSubject.set(fileSubject);
}
public String getFileSubject() {
    return fileSubject.get();
}
public StringProperty fileSubjectProperty() {
    return fileSubject;
}

public void setFileDate(String fileDate){
    this.fileDate.set(fileDate);
}
public String getFileDate() {
    return fileDate.get();
}
public StringProperty fileDateProperty() {
    return fileDate;
}

public void setFileRemarks(String fileRemarks){
    this.fileRemarks.set(fileRemarks);
}
public String getFileRemarks() {
    return fileRemarks.get();
}
public StringProperty fileRemarksProperty(){
    return fileRemarks;
}

/**
* Default constructor.
*/
public FileModel(){
    this(null,null, null);
}

/**
*Constructor with some initial data.
*
*@param 
*
*/

public FileModel(String fileSubject, String fileDate, String fileRemarks){
    this.fileSubject = new SimpleStringProperty(fileSubject);
    this.fileDate = new SimpleStringProperty(fileDate);
    this.fileRemarks = new SimpleStringProperty(fileRemarks);
}

}
```

Wrapper Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "files")
public class FileListWrapper {

private List<FileModel> files;

@XmlElement(name = "file")
public List<FileModel> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(List<FileModel> files) {
    this.files = files;
}

}
```

That is how I am unmarshalling it:

```
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(FileListWrapper.class);
 Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
 File file = new File("xxxxxxxxxx/xxx/x/xxxx/x.xml");
        // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
        FileListWrapper wrapper = (FileListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
        fileData.clear();
        fileData.addAll(wrapper.getFiles());
```

Now I am adding the extracted data into the tableview and later implementing a search on it as below:

```
private FileListWrapper wrapper;
private ObservableList<FileModel> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private void initialize(){
    //Initialize the file table with the two columns.
    fileSubjectColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->         cellData.getValue().fileSubjectProperty());
    fileDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fileDateProperty());
// ******* BUT AT THIS POINT IT GIVES THE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.******
masterData.addAll(wrapper.getFiles());

FilteredList<FileModel> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData, p -> true);

//This is my textfield which is to be used for the search.
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(file -> {
                // If filter text is empty, display all data.
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }


                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (file.getFileSubject().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches the File Subject.
                } else if (file.getFileDate().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches the File Date.
                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });

        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
        SortedList<FileModel> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
        //    Otherwise, sorting the TableView would have no effect.
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(fileTable.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        fileTable.setItems(sortedData);
}
```

It gives me a null pointer exception when I do

```
masterData.addAll(wrapper.getFiles());
```

How can I make it correct?

Comment: Either `masterData` is `null`, or `wrapper` is `null` (or possibly both). Since you don't show the code where you initialize those, it's hard to help.

Comment: It looks like you haven't initialized `wrapper`

Comment: @James_D see the unmarshalling method the `wrapper` is initialized. The wrapper returns the data as soon as it is in unmarshalling method. But when I assign it's value to masterData in my controller class it gives the null pointer exception.

Comment: @James_D you were right. Though I knew the issue was the same but I just ignored one of my methods.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging just helped me fixing it. The issue I was having was that I was using the init() method for the filtering but that was just to define the structure of the table where as in a method that was called after the init() method I was feeding the data to the table. So, the I was filtering a null ObservableList in the above code. Its my mistake that I haven't mentioned my that method in the question because of some restrictions.